# Decoding Google Closure-compiled JavaScript stack traces

Tags: php, javascript, stack-trace, google-closure-compiler, end-user

We have a reporting system that automatically logs and collates stack traces of errors from a live web application compiled with **Google Closure**.

I have the source maps on the server and I am looking for a simple way to decode the compiled source code locations back into the original source locations either in **JavaScript**, or preferably with **PHP**.

**Is there anything already out there?**

Note that these are stack traces automatically reported from our end users, not browsers that we have direct access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stack trace decoding is complicated by the fact that browsers other than Chrome haven't reported column numbers in the stack trace (IE10 may, I haven't check).  But for Chrome stack traces, I written decoders a couple of time and they work well.

There is a general Source Map library written in JavaScript available here:
https://github.com/mozilla/source-map